# DocuSign Documents retrieval

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to retrieve documents from DocuSign server .I am sending account id and document id as a parameter .Using below method to get doclist from docusign server .

```
 EnvelopeDocumentsResult docsList = envelopesApi.ListDocuments(accountID, envelopeid);
```

I am getting this error :

> The specified Integrator Key was not found or is disabled. An
>   Integrator key was not specified.

ListDocuments method accepting only two parameters but it is showing integrator key is missing .

Please help how can I fix this issue?

Comment: It would help if you show more code, especially what you are doing BEFORE you make the API request.  Are you first hitting the login endpoint and retrieving your `baseUrl` and using that in subsequent requests?

Comment: No .I am retrieving account id and send it to above method .I am calling that method .

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may be using the C# client (https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client)?

If so, please note the formation of the `authHeader` in their sample code, eg

```
 // configure 'X-DocuSign-Authentication' header
 string authHeader = "{\"Username\":\"" + username + "\", \"Password\":\"" + password + "\", \"IntegratorKey\":\"" + integratorKey + "\"}";
 Configuration.Default.AddDefaultHeader("X-DocuSign-Authentication", authHeader);
```

and follow their sample code further down about how to login BEFORE instaciating and using `envelopesApi` (as ergin mentioned) eg:

```
AuthenticationApi authApi = new AuthenticationApi();
LoginInformation loginInfo = authApi.Login();
```